# Intento leer un archivo csv y sale un error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

me aparece este error al querer leer el archivo y no sé cual sea la razón UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 400: invalid continuation byte.
He tratado de ver videos pero ninguno me ha ayudado, pensé que quizá había un poblema con pandas pero no lo creo.
Soy muy nuevo en esto y no tengo idea de lo que esté pasando ya que literalmente he estado haciendo paso a paso lo que se me ha indicado en donde estoy aprendiendo.

```
import pandas as pd
    pd.read_csv('Ordenes_productos_C1_M2.csv')
    UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[2], line 1
    ----> 1 pd.read_csv('Ordenes_productos_C1_M2.csv')

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:912, in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, date_format, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options, dtype_backend)
    899 kwds_defaults = _refine_defaults_read(
    900     dialect,
    901     delimiter,
   (...)
    908     dtype_backend=dtype_backend,
    909 )
    910 kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
--> 912 return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:577, in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    574 _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
    576 # Create the parser.
--> 577 parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    579 if chunksize or iterator:
    580     return parser

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1407, in TextFileReader.__init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
   1404     self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
   1406 self.handles: IOHandles | None = None
-> 1407 self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py:1679, in TextFileReader._make_engine(self, f, engine)
   1676     raise ValueError(msg)
   1678 try:
-> 1679     return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
   1680 except Exception:
   1681     if self.handles is not None:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py:93, in CParserWrapper.__init__(self, src, **kwds)
     90 if kwds["dtype_backend"] == "pyarrow":
     91     # Fail here loudly instead of in cython after reading
     92     import_optional_dependency("pyarrow")
---> 93 self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
     95 self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
     97 # error: Cannot determine type of 'names'

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:550, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:639, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:850, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:861, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._check_tokenize_status()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx:2021, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 400: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 1):

El error que te está dando surge cuando intentas leer un archivo con un encoding erróneo. Los encodings sirven para convertir datos de un formato a otro, y al utilizar pandas.read_csv, este tiene el encoding 'utf-8' por defecto.

Para solucionar el error, crea una lista con los encodings más utilizados e itera sobre ellos hasta conseguir el encoding adecuado. Tienes la lista de encodings [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530142/list-of-pandas-read-csv-encoding-list) aunque los más comunes son 'utf-8', 'latin1', 'ascii', 'unicode', 'iso-8859-1', 'utf-16'.

Por lo tanto, si crearas una función para manejar el error te quedaría así:

```
import pandas as pd
def read_encoded_csv(csv: str):
    encodings = ['utf-8', 'latin1', 'ascii', 'unicode', 'iso-8859-1', 'utf-16']
    for encoding in encodings:
        try:
            leer_csv = pd.read_csv(csv, encoding=encoding)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            continue
        else:
            return leer_csv
```

También podrías obtener el encoding sin tener que iterar sobre la lista utilizando la función detect de la librería chardet:

```
import chardet
def detect_encoding(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
        result = chardet.detect(f.read())
    return result['encoding']
```

[Enlace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) con todos los encodings

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que `read_csv` al leer el archivo intenta decodificarlo usando UTF-8 como codificación pero el archivo no esta creado usando dicha [codificación de caracteres](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codificaci%C3%B3n_de_caracteres).

`\xf1` es el byte que codifica la "***ñ***" en *ISO-8859-1* (Latin-1) y sus sucesoras *Windows-1252* e *ISO-8859-15*. Dado nuestro contexto lingüístico y mas aun si ese csv viene de un sistema Windows... yo empezaría por ellas. Para ello usa el parámetro `encoding` de `read_csv`:

```
pd.read_csv('Ordenes_productos_C1_M2.csv', encoding="latin-1")
```

Cuando no se especifica la codificación a usar `pandas.read_csv` usa utf-8 por defecto. En el caso del *builtin* `open(`) de Python se usa una codificación por defecto basada en el entorno, variando entre sistemas operativos por ejemplo.

En general es mala practica usar `open()` y variantes sin especificar el *encoding* de forma explicita. El problema es que hay veces que no sabemos el encoding que usa el archivo realmente.

En un mundo ideal, **la información de la codificación usada siempre se debería proporcionar por el creador del archivo junto a este**, ya que quien crea el archivo es el que sabe con seguridad que codificación usa.

Si tu fuente del archivo no proporciona esa información, solo te queda intentar deducirla. Hay casos en los que esto es relativamente fácil porque algunas codificaciones tiene características que las identifican claramente, como secuencias de bytes muy concretas. En otros casos esto no es para nada sencillo.

Puedes ir probando distintas codificaciones o usar algún sistema heurístico automatizado como bien sugiere [la respuesta de Daniel Sánchez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/612667/15089), pero si me gustaría hacer una advertencia:

**Ten en cuenta que una misma secuencia de bytes puede ser decodificada usando distintas codificaciones sin generar ningún error y obteniendo un texto "valido". Esto resulta en [*mojibakes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)**.

Dependiendo del contexto en el que estés esto puede ser un autentico problema y fuente de dolores de cabeza, con perdida de información de por medio.

Por ejemplo, supongamos que tenemos un archivo de texto con el siguiente contenido (en hex):

```
\x41\x6e\x64\x72\xc3\xa9\x73\x20\x50\xc3\xa9\x72\x65\x7a\x20\x47\x61\x72\x63\xc3\xad\x61
```

Si leemos esos datos usando UTF-8:

```
import io


data = b"\x41\x6e\x64\x72\xc3\xa9\x73\x20\x50\xc3\xa9\x72\x65\x7a\x20\x47\x61\x72\x63\xc3\xad\x61"

file = io.BytesIO(data)

with io.TextIOWrapper(file, encoding='utf8') as file_obj:
    print(file_obj.read())
```

Tenemos la salida:

> ```
> Andrés Pérez García
> ```

Pero si usamos Latin-1 (ISO/IEC 8859-1):

```
with io.TextIOWrapper(file, encoding='latin-1') as file_obj:
    print(file_obj.read())
```

no tenemos ningún error, pero la salida es:

> ```
> AndrÃ©s PÃ©rez GarcÃ­a
> ```

Moraleja, ten cuidado cuando intentes inferir la codificación de un archivo, cualquier sistema que uses es proclive a tener este tipo de errores (no siempre tan obvios como mi ejemplo) y dar por valida una codificación cuando no lo es.

La codificación y las zonas horarias son fuente de pesadillas y traumas comunes, especialmente de gente que administra bases de datos...